# Handle Notification data without click on notification in ionic 3 (One signal push notification)

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

i am using Onesignal in ionic 3. I am getting notification properly when the app is in foreground. When I receive a notification in background i am getting the data in the notification only after tapping the notification. But i want to get the data without tapping on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Silent Notifications (Silent Notifications are background notifications that do not show any message on the device)

Right now, you're likely using the `onOpened` handler. You will need to set up a service extension and be prepared to have to write native code!

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/silent-notifications